# How to use labels of new Renderer(createed with GUI) in code (LWUIT v1.5)

Tags: lwuit

I've created a Renderer in Resource Editor with three labels(Icon,Destination,lblDate).

And used it in the list with Listmodel event in StateMachine.java

```
cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(payments));
         cmp.setRenderer(new  DefaultListCellRenderer(false) {
        public Component getCellRendererComponent(Component list, Object model, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected) {
               if(value instanceof Payment) { 
                   Payment r = (Payment)value;
                 super.getCellRendererComponent(list, model, r.getPhoneNumber(), index, isSelected);                     
                 setText( r.toString());
                return this;
               }
               return super.getCellRendererComponent(list, model, value, index, isSelected);
        }     
    });
```

In this code I've could only change the Destination label of renderer

```
setText( r.toString());
```

but how to use other labels for example lblDate? How to set them values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the GUI builder for the renderer, you can see a detailed video on how to use that in the [Codename One Blog](http://codenameone.blogspot.com/2010/12/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-6.html). You are using a DefaultListCellRenderer which is a label so it can only contain a String and an Image, you need to use a more elaborate base and implement the ListCellRenderer interface or use the standard GUI builder support with the Hashtable data model.

Comment: I do use Resource Editor like in the video Codename One Blog except I want to fill the list from the code. Could you please show me any sample of using listrenderer created by Resource Editor in the code. Or I should override DefaultListCellRenderer class and not use the Resource Editor in this case?

Comment: The moment you call setRenderer that means you AREN'T using the GUI builder for that... Filling the list is easy just like you did. Only you used Payment objects instead of Hashtable's which the list renderer in the GUI builder can't render. So you need to either: use a Hashtable for your data (and don't use the setRenderer). Or implement a Renderer properly, see the Scroll demo in the LWUITDemo.

Comment: Payment is an object but payments is Vector of Payment objects.

Comment: I said vector of Hashtables! If you aren't using that you should build a renderer like its done in the LWUIT demo. Did you look at the LWUIT demo source code for the Scroll demo?

Comment: can I create a Hashtable and bind it to the renderer in the code not in GUI? Main idea is to fill the list(with renderer that created in GUI) inside the code. To use the complex renderer that designed in GUI.

Comment: That's the whole idea. The hashtable keys map directly to the names of the elements within the renderer. With a class of your own you would have to implement the logic yourself.

Comment: but I've got another problem. When I change the item of the vector the list stays unchanged. How do I refresh the list items?

Answer (score -1):

I've just came up to the answer of Shai Almog. Thanks.
The answer is to use Vector of Hashtable that structured like renderer in GUI.

GUI:

[image]

sample code:

```
  Vector PaymentsHashVec = new Vector() ;
   for(int iter = 0 ; iter < getPayments().size() ; iter++) {
      Hashtable hsh = new Hashtable();
      Payment p = (Payment)getPayments().elementAt(iter);
      hsh.put("phn", p.getPhoneNumber()) ;
      hsh.put("ant",p.getOriginalAmount()+"/ " + p.getAmount()) ;
      hsh.put("btm",p.getDateSubmitted()) ;
      PaymentsHashVec.addElement(hsh);                                  
   }
 cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(PaymentsHashVec));
```